# Python scikit-learn Imputer import error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a silly question. I'm working on Pyhton using the Intellij IDE. I'm trying to import the below:

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

However, I receive the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): from sklearn.preprocessing import
>   Imputer

Can you please help with this?

Comment: And whats the error. Please post the complete error.

Comment: which version of sklearn are you using? type: import sklearn and then sklearn.__version__. In version 0.19, it does exists (sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer). In case, you have another version of sklearn, then upgrade it by using: pip (or pip3) install scikit-learn=0.19.1

Comment: @Sanchit In the future, I'd suggest you add your own answer instead of commenting the answer/modifying a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use the latest version of **scikit-learn** library.  Install it by using the following command (sometimes **sudo** is required before **pip**):

```
pip (or, pip3) install scikit-learn==0.19.1
```

the = symbol must be replaced by ==